# Let users of my website upload photos

Tags: web-services

Is there an online service that will let users of my website upload photos to the service , and a plugin that can retrieve these photos dynamically and display them on a webpage ?

The reason I ask, is that I have limited server space ,so uploading elsewhere is preferred

Comment: http://imgur.com/ ?  I think it's what SO uses.  I'm sure there are tons of other options too if you google for it.

Comment: User **Gravatar** http://en.gravatar.com/ . you will get more code samples also.

Comment: @Merlyn - I was thinking the same thing.  I still wonder how long it will be until imgur gets bought out and crippled, or shutdown due to insane bandwidth.  I still remember the day Alan released it and how everyone on reddit basically said "your gonna lose your shorts trying to scale this" ... amazing that he can keep it afloat.

Answer (score 0):

you can use amazon s3. It is much reliable solution.

http://www.google.com/search?q=Amazon+S3&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t